# how to display multiple products on my created custom module in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

Created products subcategory want to display all the products that are listed in the category.

The below snippet gives me single product details, I want all the products listed

```
<?php
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); //getting product model

$_product = $model->load($productid); //getting product object for particular product id

echo $_product->getShortDescription(); //product's short description
echo $_product->getDescription(); // product's long description
echo $_product->getName(); //product name
echo $_product->getPrice(); //product's regular Price
echo $_product->getSpecialPrice(); //product's special Price
echo $_product->getProductUrl(); //product url
echo $_product->getImageUrl(); //product's image url
echo $_product->getSmallImageUrl(); //product's small image url
echo $_product->getThumbnailUrl(); //product's thumbnail image url   

?>
```

Comment: You can get product collection with your category filter and then display required information on your page.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya could you provide code snippet?

Comment: below answer has the code you can use to get products with category filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all product with the current category or you can pass the category id in below code.

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
    if (empty($category)) {
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    $categoryId = reset($product->getCategoryIds());
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId); // you can pass category ID also.
}

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

This may be help.

**EDIT**

[click here](https://blog.amasty.com/10-best-free-magento-themes-2016/)

Comment: can you suggest me a free bootstrap magento  1.9 x theme?

Comment: I edit my answer and you can see demo and download the themes